# Create safe Control.ID string from user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, sanitization

Is there anything existing within .net to create a safe `Control.ID` property from a string such that it satisfies the following criteria (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid values for this property. Including spaces or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error.

So can I take a string for example:

`Hello world`

And get back something like:

`hello_world`

I know i could write something custom to do this but it seems like their ought to be something that already exists to do this, so far I haven't found anything though.

Comment: You could try [`Server.URLEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738(v=vs.90).aspx), replace `%` with `_`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - I don't think that will work, from the link: `'Spaces ( ) are converted to plus signs (+)'` - which would be an invalid character.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are willing to write something custom, which I think would be best it's pretty straightforward.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = "some user input";
    Regex r =  new Regex(@"\W|_");
    var x = r.Replace(s, "_");
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.WriteLine(r.Replace("http://google.com?s=search query here", "_"));

}
```

> some_user_input
>
> http___google_com_s_search_query_here

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to convert generated control names back to original string, you could use string's hash codes instead of string's text:

```
    public string GetControlName(string userInput)
    {
        var hashCode = userInput.GetHashCode();

        string controlName;

        if (hashCode < 0)
        {
            controlName = String.Concat("uc_", -hashCode);
        }
        else
        {
            controlName = String.Concat("uc", hashCode);
        }

        return controlName;
    }
```

This gives you:

> Hello world
>
> **uc_1660742776**
>
> some user input
>
> **uc_1363708559**
>
> http://google.com?s=search query here
>
> **uc_2146180550**

Another possible way is to use one of SHA algorithms (SHA1, SHA256, ...):

```
    public string GetSHAControlName(string userInput)
    {
        using (var sha = SHA1.Create())
        {
            var input = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(userInput);

            var hash = sha.ComputeHash(input);
            
            return string.Concat("uc", GetStringFromHash(hash));
        }
    }

    public static string GetStringFromHash(byte[] hash)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            result.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Which gives you:

> Hello world
>
> **uc7B502C3A1F48C8609AE212CDFB639DEE39673F5E**
>
> some user input
>
> **uc2503971E0748D1CCBFB2022D3332ACF903EB4B8F**
>
> http://google.com?s=search query here
>
> **ucBBD010B90C6804F25E1B0AF2C1464278AB9BC08C**